# DSE cluster disk consumption

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I am currently "trying" to create a sound model for my data in DSE graph. But it currently has no data, just the unfinished "schema" definition.

- about 30 (in total) properties / vertexes and edges defined

I haven't managed to check on it for a couple of days - and I have just found that my cluster is now consuming 4 times the disk space  that it was when I last looked it.

I am not so worried about the capacity of the cluster... I have plenty to go around... And there are plenty of Q&A's about trying to reclaim Cassandra disk space, too - but again - I have no data... there is nothing to delete and reclaim.

So my question is how can my cluster be consuming 220 MB, per node (give or take 15 - according to OpsCenter)? and more worrying - two and a bit days ago - it told me it was consuming 240 MB for the whole cluster. (Which I still thought was ridiculously, too much - given I have only 1 user created keyspace (graph) - with no data.

I am worried about;

- Why it is "growing" despite no changes
- The rate of change in 2.5 days.

As always - Thanks!
-Gavin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that you are using OpsCenter.   OpsCenter collects metrics about your cluster and stores it in tables.  When you start with an empty cluster the Opscenter metrics can quickly take more room than your data, but on a normal production cluster the Opscenter data becomes much less of a factor.  You should first find out if Opscenter is the culprit by running nodetool cfstats and looking at "Space used (total)" to see if the space is being used by Opscenter.  If it is you have three choices:

1- Live with it.  Now that you know the source it may not be a bad thing
2- Reduce the data Opscenter collects
3- Have Opscenter store it's data in a different cluster

Here is a link to the latest doc that may help:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.0/opsc/configure/opscConfigureDataCollectionExpiration_c.html

Comment: Thanks - seems so simple once someone points it out to you!
The stats from OpsCenter was the cause of the data growth. 
And it all comes down to what you monitor and the TTL for that data... 
I stopped using the OpsCenter for about 2 weeks - and noticed after a cleanup - the nodes we back to practically nothing.... since I am still getting the schema worked out and the data is very minimal at the moment.

In my defence - it was just the sudden and magnitueds of difference that threw me.